# Insert new column values in dataframe with MultiIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
          rank     num      rank    num
          2015     2015     2014    2014   
France    8        1200     9       1216   
Italy     11       789      10      788
```

I want to add a new column in the multi-index, called `corrected_num`, and I want the value of this column to be the value of `num` for the corresponding row, divided by a number obtained from another dictionary, which looks like this:

```
b = {2015: 10, 2014: 12}
```

In other words, I'd like to end up with something like this:

```
          rank     num      num_corrected    rank    num    num_corrected
          2015     2015     2015             2014    2014   2014
France    8        1200     120              9       1216   101.3
Italy     11       789      78.9             10      788    65.6
```

So far my approach is to iterate over each row in the dataframe, then over each column in the row, something like this:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    for year in df.num.columns:
        df.set_value(i, 'num_corrected, ' + year, row.frequency[year] / b[year])
```

But when I try this my Jupyter notebook freezes, so I'm hoping there's a better way!

Comment: It's hard to tell if your years are the second level of the columnar multi-index or not. Can you include the code to produce your dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

***setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [8, 1200, 9, 1216],
        [11, 789, 10, 788]
    ],
    ['France', 'Italy'],
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['rank', 'num'], [2015, 2014]])
).sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
```

Make `b` a series

```
b = pd.Series({2015: 10, 2014: 12})
```

***method 1***

```
num_c = df.num / b

cols = num_c.columns
num_c.columns = [['num_corrected'] * len(cols), cols]

pd.concat([df, num_c], axis=1)
```

[image]

***method 2***

```
d1 = df.stack()
d1['num_corrected'] = d1.num / d1.index.get_level_values(1).to_series().map(b).values
d1.unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
```

[image]